# Symfony2 How to display two forms in one view

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I would like to display a newsletter form twice on the page. Once in the footer on the base template (layout.html.twig) which will be always displayed and then again on the underConstruction page which inherits the base template.

```
{{ render(controller('DbeDonaciBundle:Newsletter:new')) }}
```

After testing the form i figured out that only the one in the underConstruction page is working, why that?

```
   /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('email', 'email', array(
              "required"=>true)
              );
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help guys! :-)

Comment: please provide your `NewsletterController::newAction` code

Comment: Your two forms may have the same variable name "form", then Symfony will render only the first.

Comment: Please provide a different name for each form

Comment: public function newAction() {
  $entity = new Newsletter();
  $form = $this -> createCreateForm($entity);

  return $this -> render('HaHansBundle:Newsletter:new.html.twig', array('entity' => $entity, 'form' => $form -> createView(), ));
 }

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. User different name (for same form object) for view variable
2. Clone the form object (then ofcourse you must use 2 variables for view ) in controller